# Capture click event before page load and trigger after DOM ready

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax

I am working on an E-commerce site where on product listing page when the user clicks on Add Cart button 
product will be added to cart and we are showing an popup box saying the product added... We are using Plugin for showing popup box and data for popup is coming from ajax and java controller. It is working fine well when the entire page loaded successfully. If the user clicks on Add Cart while the page load its showing plain ajax result instead of Popup because the Plugin using for Popup is not available during page load. We tried disabling the Add Cart button till page load but client is not happy with this approach.

Code:

```
<--!form for add to cart-->
 <form submit="addcart()">
  <input type="button">Add Cart</button>
 </form>

 //JS for show popup and save form data
 saveform:function{
 }

 displayPopup:function{
 }

 productadd:function{
   saveform();
   displayPopup();
 }

$(document).ready(function(){
   productadd();
 }
```

Is there any workaround to capture the click event during page load and trigger the click event automatically for particular button if user already clicked on. Please suggest me any other solution to show popup properly.

Thanks In Advance:)

Comment: Sounds like you should be working on faster pageloads instead ?

Comment: It's working fine for faster Internet speed but user want it to work on very slow connection also:)

Answer (score 0):

Your option is not to use inline JS, which is not recommended nowadays anyway. In this case, you risk calling the `addcart()` function when the JS file has not been downloaded and parsed.

The solution is to use JS to bind the click event to the submit form upon DOM ready, so that the click event will only be meaningful once JS is loaded. For your HTML, remove the inline JS:

```
<form>
    <input type="button">Add Cart</button>
</form>
```

Instead, listen to the submit event using JS:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    productadd();

    $('form').submit(function() {
        addcart();
    });
});
```

Also, you might want to look at the reason why your site is loading so slowly (or at least the JS). Are you serving it as a gzipped file? Is there anyway to minimize it (only the production version)?